# Why does dhclient <interface> return a services related message?

Tags: 11.10, networking, command-line, dhclient

I'm trying to use dhclient to set up a tether with dhclient, which worked in 11.04. However, upon upgrading to 11.10, I get the following message when trying to use it.

> Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the sevice(8) utility, e.g. service smbd reload
>
> Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, you may also use the reload(8) utility, e.g. reload smbd
>   RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Answer (score 1):

dhclient was converted to an upstart job, which is just another way of managing services, a number of things were converted to that in Natty and Oneiric.  If you run sudo service dhclient start you're going to see the message "RTNETLINK answers: File exists" that appears to be the actual problem you're having.  The init script is actually running the upstart job for you, but there's a problem with starting dhclient.  From a quick Google, it looks like you may have a problem in your network interface configuration.